# My server is responding OpenSSL: : SSL: : SSLError: Receivedfatalalert: handshake_failure

Tags: php, docker, ssl

I have taken a project builded with Laravel 4.2 and PHP 5.6.

And have mounted the server with Docker.

This the docker configuration:

……  The server uses Nginx, certificates from Let’s Encrypt with Certbot.
This are the configuration files of the Nginx:

```
nginx.conf erver {

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

        server_name example.com.py www.example.com.py;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Cetbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/propar.com.py/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/propar.com.py/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

and options-ssl-nginx.conf

```
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:40m; #holds approx 40 x 4000 sessions
ssl_session_timeout 2h;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
```

The project is an E-commerce that conects with a local Credit Card Payments procesor company.  Everthing works fine until the Payments procesor, responds to a url in my server for payment confirmation.  Here my server responds  [Status 500]  OpenSSL: : SSL: : SSLError: Receivedfatalalert: handshake_failure

I have no error or anything in my laravel.log.  I copy pasted the same request and reproduced it with postman and it works fine returning the correct 200 response.  The payment procesor told me that i need to validate only certificates with TLS1.2 and above and as you can see in my nginx.conf file, thats already validated.  Does Anyone knows what could be missing? Thanks in advance